# The form of a matrix $A=e_{I}A=Ae_{J}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M_{n}(\mathbb{F})$ be all n by n matrices over a field $\mathbb{F}$. We denote by $e_i \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ the matrix with $1$ at $(i,i)$ entry and $0$ elsewhere. Let $I=\{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_\ell \}$ be a $\ell$-subset of the set $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, $\ell \geq 1$. We denote by $e_{I}$ the matrix $e_{i_1}+e_{i_2}+\cdots+e_{i_\ell}$.

Let $I, \ J$ be two subsets of the set $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $|I|=|J|$. If $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{F})$ and $A=e_{I}A=Ae_{J}$, I want to know whether 
\begin{align*}
A=\begin{cases}
A_{IJ} \in M_{|I|}(\mathbb{F}) & \textrm{at $(I,J)$ position}, \\
0 & \textrm{elsewhere},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $A_{IJ}$ is a $|I| \times |J|$ minor of $A$ that corresponds to the rows with index in $I$ and the columns with index in $J$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $A_{IJ}$ supposed to mean? What do you mean by $I, J \in [n]$ ($I$ and $J$ were supposed to be subsets of $[n]$)? How should a $n$ by $n$ matrix ($A$) be equal to a $|I|$ by $|I|$ matrix (which $A_{IJ}$ seems to be)?

Comment: It seems to me that you have come up with a number of definitions and non-standard symbols. This is fine to do, and your writing seems clear for the most part. One usually defines things with the purpose of proving things, though. So if there is some math problem that you are working on that will be simplified by these definitions, I wish you well. One concern that I have heard before with regards to new notation, though, is that it can throw people off who are used to using the old notation. I believe such an issue with notation was even described by Paul Erdos in his biography.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? You ask us to check your reasoning, but you didn't write any argument…

Comment: @ A.P Thank you. Please you look the question again.

Comment: Yes, a that's very easy to prove, because multiplying on the left by $e_i^T$ selects the $i$-th row of $A$, while multiplying on the right by $e_j$ selects the $j$-th column.

Comment: @ A.P. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @ Matthias Klupsch Thank you for your comment.